# Security measures when brewing Soda

Tags: soda

I just wanted to experiment homebrewing some Soda for a kick. I found a few pages online that say the process is quite similar to homebrewing Beer, but somewhat easier and faster. As far as I know, I could heat some water, mix yeast with any kind "juice", let it rest for a day and get something of a Soda.

My question is, what safety measures should I take into consideration? Should I avoid using some kind of product? Are there any chemicals that could be harmful when combined with yeast?
For instance, if I wanted to experiment carbonating a "Crystal Light" instead of using real Juice, could that have unforeseen consequences?

Answer (score 1):

Provided you aren't making a fermented soda, making soda is like bottling day for beer. You are essentially preparing the ingredients and carbonating. If you do this with priming sugar and yeast, you do actually create a small amount of alcohol (~0.25%). However, you do have some of the the same sanitation concerns and precautions. If you bottle your soda with unwanted microbes, you can get an infection and ruin your soda the same as with beer or worse, since there are potentially a lot more sugars. I don't know what ingredients are in Crystal Light, but I would suspect any commercial product may have issues because they typically include preservatives that will hinder the yeast. Force carbonating with CO2 would work fine, since there is no fermentation involved.